# Keywords/formats I can look for to find lost chrome/opera 'Recent tabs' file?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, data-recovery, opera, tabs

The situation: Some time ago i used chrome and was slowly switching to opera to browse the internet. Then chrome updated and in the process wiped out all the tabs i usually used, and i couldn't restore because the 'restore previous session was blank. Further compounding the issue was that a few weeks later my computer crashed multiple times in quick succession, wiping out the opera session as well because my computer crashed in the midst of opera restoring its tabs.

I used photorec to restore deleted files and stored them in an outside hard drive in the hope that I could find the tabs I've lost, but I'm not sure if I've done the process correctly since the first one ended with "syntax error, inter" and the second has gone to pass 2 rather fast in my (admittedly inexperienced) eyes.

Before I continue to use my computer, I'd like to search and see if I can find the tabs. However, photorec also reclaimed a lot of other txt files, so I don't know if they're there or not. Is there a specific syntax I can use to search for the lost sessions in chrome and opera?